# Сломалась страница истории проверок

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, очередь-проверок

Собственно, вот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ник сливается с названием вопроса, а результат проверки вообще не отображается.

---

## UPD

Немного ошибся. Результаты проверки отображаются, но они ушли далеко вправо. Вчера не заметил горизонтальный скролл.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]